# How to Put Textbox and DropDownList in GridView for Editing

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, textbox

I'm sorry. I'm really new at this but I'm trying really hard.
So I really need help on how to put a textbox and a dropdownlist in gridview for editing.

This is my codes of my GridView

```
<div id="id_tm1" runat="server" class="grid" style="border: 1px solid black; overflow: scroll;
                            width: 94%; height: 103px" visible="true">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvGroup" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="True"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="Silver" BorderWidth="1px" Height="77px"
                                Width="98%">
                                <RowStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JOBTITLE" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#666666" HeaderText="Job Title"
                                        ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="BUSINESS_UNIT" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#666666" HeaderText="Business Unit"
                                        ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DIVISION" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#666666" HeaderText="Division"
                                        ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB_DIVISION" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#666666" HeaderText="Sub-Division"
                                        ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CLASSIFICATION" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#666666" HeaderText="Classification"
                                        ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB_CLASSIFICATION" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#666666" HeaderText="Sub-Classification"
                                        ItemStyle-Height="10px" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                </Columns>
                                <PagerStyle Font-Size="9pt" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <div style="width: 100%; font-size: 10pt; text-align: center; color: Red;">
                                        No record found.
                                    </div>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="DarkGray" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt"
                                    ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
```

I tried to put `<asp:dropdownlist>` and `<asp:templatefield>` but I'm having an error "Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField' does not have a public property named 'TemplateField' or 'DropDownList'

The textbox and dropdownlist should appear when I click the Edit button in the gridview item list and be able to edit it. [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUyd7.png)
Thank you.

Comment: Have you some code yet? Take a look [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Comment: Make a fiddler with your code. I easy to work around.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">

        <tr>
            <td>Job title</td>
            <td>
                Busines Unit
            </td>
            <td> Division </td>
            <td>Sub Division</td>
            <td>Classificcation</td>
                <td>Sub Classification</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Dir marketing</td>
            <td>
                <select><option value="0">Please select</option></select>
            </td>
            <td><select><option value="0">Please select</option></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="0">Please select</option></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="0">Please select</option></select></td>
            <td><select><option value="0">Please select</option></select></td>
            <td> <button>Save</button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

You can try like this

Answer (score 0):

It can be done very easy with the **twitter-bootstrap** framework.
have a look at the **[Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)** 
Make sure you have embedded bootstrap in your `<head></head>` like this:

```
<head>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

and then in your body make something like this:

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Job Title:</label>
        <span>Dir Marketing</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Business Unit:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">--Please select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Division:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">--Please select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Sub-Division</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">--Please select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Classification:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">--Please select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">Sub-Classification:</label>
        <select>
            <option value="">--Please select--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</body>
```

this all will give you something like this:
[image: Bootstrap Table Grid-System]